# Bit of python help

Tags: python

I've tried to get this to work, but it just freezes.
It should display a pyramid, but all it does is.. halts.

```
from graphics import * 

valid_colours = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'green']
colour = ['', '', '']

while True:
    colour[0] = raw_input("Enter your first colour: ")
    colour[1] = raw_input("Enter your second colour: ")
    colour[2] = raw_input("Enter your third colour: ")
    if ((colour[0] and colour[1] and colour[2]) in valid_colours):
        break 

while True:
    width = raw_input("Enter a width between 2-7: ")
    if width.isdigit(): 
        if (int(width) <= 7 and int(width) >= 2):
            break 

width = int(width)

win = GraphWin("My Mini Project ", 1000, 1000) # 1000 \ 20 = 50
win.setCoords(0 , 0 , 20, 20)
p1 = [0, 2]

while width > 0:
    p = [1, 3]
    loopWidth = 0
    while loopWidth < width:
        loopWidth = loopWidth + 1

        c = 0
        while c <= 10:
            c = c + 1
            if c % 2: 
                colour = "white"
            else:
                colour = "red"

            rectangle = Rectangle(Point(p[0],p1[0]), Point(p[1], p1[1]))
            rectangle.setFill(colour)
            rectangle.setOutline("black")
            rectangle.draw(win)

            p[0] = p[0] + 0.2
            p1[0] = p1[0] + 0.2

        p[0] = p[0] - 2
        p1[0] = p1[0] - 2

        p[0] = p[0] + 2
        p[1] = p[1] + 2

    width = width - 1
    p1[0] = p1[0] + 2
    p1[1] = p1[1] + 2
```

Comment: (1) should post this to stackoverflow, (2) should narrow down the problem, nobody wants to do your work: they might help but you need to put in some effort

Comment: oh dear, what is it with `while` loops?

Comment: 1st: have you tried stepping through it in pdb or another debugger? have you tried debugging via print statements?
2nd: I'm going to introduce you to some friends of mine (2 in particular): for in loops (the loop around c in particular), and the += and -= assignment operators. They're very helpful and they don't bite.

Answer (score 1):

- Well first the color-input loop does not do what you want it to do.

The 'and' in `if ((colour[0] and colour[1] and colour[2]) in valid_colours):`
compares their *string* values to each other, where any non-empty string evaluates as True. The expression evaluates to colour[2], assuming it is the last non-empty string, you can prove this with: `print (colour[0] and colour[1] and colour[2])`

Change to: `if (colour[0] in valid_colours and colour[1] in valid_colours and colour[2] in valid_colours):`

- Your main rectangle-drawing loop:
  The intent of the following code is to iterate from 1..width (inclusively)

:

```
barloopWidth = 0
while loopWidth < width:
    loopWidth = loopWidth + 1
    do stuff using (loopWidth + 1)
```

so replace it with:
    for loopWidth in range(1,width+1):

- The loop iterating c and colour through 6 loops of white,red can be rewritten using '*' (the sequence replication operator):

  for colour in ['white','red']*6:

So your main loop becomes:

```
while width > 0:
    p = [1, 3]

    for loopWidth in range(1,width+1):
        for colour in ['white','red']*6:

            #Draw your rectangles

            p[0]  += 2
            p1[0] += 2

        p[0] -= 2
        p1[0] -= 2

        p[0] = p[0] + 2
        p[1] = p[1] + 2

    width = width - 1
    p1[0] += 2
    p1[1] += 2
```

- As to why it hangs on your pyramid coordinates loop, debug it yourself using print:
  `print 'Drawing rectangle from (%d,%d) to (%d,%d)'% (p[0],p1[0],p[1],p1[1])`

You might find it helpful for testing to isolate that code info a function draw_pyramid(), away from get_colors().